# Variance of Matrix Trace

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random-matrices, random-functions

Given a random variables $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and a constant real matrix $Z$, how can the variance given by $Var[Tr(ZXX^T)]$ be calculated? Note that  $Z$ is p.s.d and $X$ is $N (0,C)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\operatorname{Var}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left(ZXX^T\right)\right]=\operatorname{Var}\left[\operatorname{Tr}\left(X^TZX\right)\right]=\operatorname{Var}\left[X^TZX\right]\;.
$$

Beyond that not much can be said without knowing anything about $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: Edited: $Z$ is p.s.d and $X$ is $N (0,C)$